# How to install gcc/g++ 4.4 and make links

Tags: installation, apt, gcc, symbolic-link, g++

Because I cannot compile some code by gcc/g++ 4.7, I want to install gcc/g++ 4.4.

I searched the Internet and found some different way. I don't know what is the best solution.

Is it possible to choose what version I want to use without make a "gcc" link again?

Answer (score 1):

Just install the [`gcc-4.4`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-4.4) [image: Install gcc-4.4] and [`g++-4.4`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/g++-4.4) [image: Install g++-4.4] packages and make sure you *call* the right compiler version on the command line, e.g.

```
g++-4.4 [options]
```

Depending on the source you are trying to compile, you can usually specify the compiler in the `Makefile`.

You might want to switch the default compiler on your system by telling Ubuntu this using `update-alternatives`, e.g.

```
update-alternatives --config cc
update-alternatives --config c++
```

Note that this is a system-wide setting, so I would not recommend doing this unless compiling this source is the only purpose of this system.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that you need additional libs while trying to compile different applications. So if you're doing anything beyond your own, relatively simple, applications I would suggest install the `build-essential` package instead of just the standalone compile.

With that in mind, if you're doing the compiling manually then specify it directly on the command line, if however you're using a [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), then you can set the CC and CXX variables

```
export CC="gcc-3.4"
export CXX="g++-3.4"
```